# Add ExternalSecret to Yaml file deploying to K8s

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, dbt

I'm trying to deploy a Kubernetes processor to a cluster on GCP GKE but the pod fails with the following error:

```
secret "service-account-credentials-dbt-test" not found: CreateContainerConfigError
```

This is my deployment.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dbt-core-processor
  namespace: prod
  labels:
    app: dbt-core
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dbt-core
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dbt-core
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: dbt-core-processor
        image: IMAGE
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
            memory: 1Gi
          limits:
            cpu: 1
            memory: 2Gi
        env:
        - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: service-account-credentials-dbt-test
              key: service-account-credentials-dbt-test
---
apiVersion: kubernetes-client.io/v1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: service-account-credentials-dbt-test
  namespace: prod
spec:
  backendType: gcpSecretsManager
  data:
  - key: service-account-credentials-dbt-test
    name: service-account-credentials-dbt-test
    version: latest
```

When I run `kubectl apply -f deployment.yml` I get the following error:

```
deployment.apps/dbt-core-processor created
error: unable to recognize "deployment.yml": no matches for kind "ExternalSecret" in version "kubernetes-client.io/v1"
```

This creates my processor but the pod fails to spin up the secrets:

```
secret "service-account-credentials-dbt-test" not found: CreateContainerConfigError
```

How do I add the secrets from my secrets manager in GCP to this deployment?

Answer (score 2):

`ExternalSecret` is a custom resource definition (CRD) and it looks like it is not installed on your cluster.

I googled `kubernetes-client.io/v1` and it looks like you may be following instructions from the old, archived project that first provided this CRD? The GitHub repo pointed me to [a maintained project](https://github.com/external-secrets/external-secrets) that has replaced it.

The good news is that the current project has what looks like comprehensive documentation, including [a guide to how to install the CRDs on your cluster and the proper configuration for the External secret](https://external-secrets.io/v0.7.0/introduction/getting-started/).

Comment: Thanks for the insight, the second link is to a a documentation with instruction for AWS deployment. Are there any with instructions for GCP deployment?

Comment: [Yes](https://external-secrets.io/v0.7.0/provider/google-secrets-manager/)